# Quick way to import a 6f mesh to use as scale throughout a scene?

Tags: scale

Is there a Quick way to import a 6f mesh to use as scale throughout a scene?
Its hard to tell what the scale is when theres not measurements around

and the option to see mesurement in Edit mode is just so limiting,

I just want to know that my mesh is 6ft
or how to make it 6ft so I get a rough idea at a glance

Comment: I would also like to know how I could scale a model to 6ft, that could work eQually as well

Comment: Please edit your A instead of adding a comment. Thank you

Comment: Select model, press N key to see properties side panel, Item tab, and check Dimension values. Also check Scene properties, there you can set units.